# "`select()` doesn't handle lists" when computing textSimilarity between two word embeddings in R

Tags: r, nlp, word-embedding, r-text

How many words in word embedding variables do you need to compute semantic similarity in r-package *text*? I’m trying to run:

```
library(text)
WEhello<-textEmbed("hello")
WEgoodbye<-textEmbed("goodbye")
textSimilarity(WEhello, WEgoodbye)
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in `dplyr::select()`:
! `select()` doesn't handle lists.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this to work you have to select the word embedding (and avoid also including the $singlewords_we). Try this:

```
textSimilarity(WEhello$x, WEgoodbye$x)
```